# Jquery content slider problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am having a bit of a problem trying to get this code to work, for some reason I just can't seem to find what is wrong. If anybody knows what I can do to make it show a slide for about 3 sec then fade out and show a new one and at the end go back to the first and loop that would be great! Below I have posted the code I have right now. I really need some help as this project is due in 2 weeks and I have a lot more work to do, thanks!

```
    <section class="clearfix">
    <div id="snapshots">
        <article>
            <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/4mem1qr1m/themes_image.png">
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/q8Em247a0/slidehome_4.png">
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/dsLm2trr5/slidehome_5.png">
        </article>
    </div>
    </section>​


    /* joey content slider function */
    window.onload = function() { 

    var time = 1500;
    var content = $('#snapshots');
    var cont = 1;


    // MARK THE ARTICLES AND CONTENT
    $(function article(){

    // how many slides 
    // an = article number
    var an = content.find("article").length;

    // define the amount of slides in a class name 
    // example: <div class="slides_6">
    content.addClass("slides_"+an);

    // slide switcher 
    content.append('<div id="switch"></div>');

    };




// FIND AND MARK SLIDES
$(function slides() {
    numb = 1;
    content.find("article").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("slide_"+numb);
        numb++;
        $(this).hide();
    });

    //setTimeout("", 4000);
}


function slider(content, time){
    content.fadeOut(time, function() {

    // plus 1 slide 
    var conta = cont+1;

    $("article.slide_"+conta).animate({
        "display": "block"
    },1500);

    $("article.slide_"+cont).animate({
        "display": "none"
    },1500);

    setTimeout("doitdude()", 4000);

    });

}


// RESET SLIDE
function reset(content, time) {

    // fade out content 
    content.fadeOut(time, function(){

    // while fading out 

    // show first slide 
    $("article.slide_1").animate({
        "display": "block"
    },1500);
     // hide the last one 
    $("article.slide_"+conta).animate({
        "display": "none"
    },1500);

    // end transition
    });


    setTimeout("doitdude()", 4000);
}


function doitdude() {
    if(cont < an) {
        slider(content, 1000);
        cont++;
    }
    else{
        var conta = cont;
        var cont = 1;
        // reset code here:
        reset()
    }


};​


    #snapshots { overflow: hidden; height: 410px; width: auto; }
    #snapshots img { }​
```

**Note:** I can't use a plugin because I am trying to make my own. Thanks!

Also a JsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UYE4E/

Comment: I have no idea what's going on here. Check your browser's console, there's syntax errors in many places. If you fix one, you get another. I'm not sure you're using the right syntax for what you actually want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function declaration is incorrect. Probably you are trying to do following:

```
(function($) {
    function foo(){
        //foo body
    };
}(jQuery) );
```

Anyway, read about JS scopes and closures.

[Article 1](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) [Article 2](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)